# How to run on demand scripts on server-side that could create a new file via Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I'd like to ask if it's possible to run scripts (bash, etc) that could read and create files, from Google Cloud Endpoints. Which Google products are appropriate? How to configure this? (Java)

(There are many google products, but the development documentations seem to be difficult to find. Even a google search could return too many different unrelated results.)

Thank you.

Comment: As you can see on the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs), Endpoints is an API management system, so endpoints is not the product for what you want to achieve, in order to be able to point you in the direction of what is the correct product I need more details in what you want to do with these scripts, eg. will they create files in a vm or in cloud storage? Will they be trigger manually or automatically by an app?

Comment: Additionaly I have found this [article in medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/executing-bash-scripts-with-a-webhook-in-google-cloud-75ea4b173c9) that might clarify some points for you.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelLemos! This is a possible answer to this issue!